# Flutter running start up several times

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have noticed while debugging my app that in the future builder in my Main MyApp class is being run twice (or sometimes seems like several times). Can any one please help let me know why this is. As further on I am also loading data from my database then it will result in making several loads when only one is required at app launch.

Here is my code:

```
void main() {
  initializeDateFormatting().then((_) => runApp(MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.black));
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
]);

return FutureBuilder(
    future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // Check for errors
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: const Text('ERROR: DID NOT INITIALIZE FIREBASE!'));
      }
      // Once complete, show application
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print("GOT HERE");
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Payments(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Auth(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Member(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Exercises(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Categories(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Teachers(),
            ),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Test',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              fontFamily: 'Gordita',
            ),
            home: AuthRootScreen(),
          ),
        );
      }

      // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Platform.isIOS
            ? CupertinoActivityIndicator()
            : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    });
```

}
}

Please note that after the following line:

if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)

There is a print statement: print("GOT HERE");
This is printing twice to the console and it is this that is showing me that the code is being executed several times.

Any help with solving this, so that my code runs more efficiently when loading would be gratefully received. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1st Initialize your providers before the MyApp() widget execute like below code.

```
runApp(
  MultiProvider(
   providers: [
     ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
       create: (context) => UserProvider(),
     ),         
   ],
   child: MyApp(),
  ),
 );
```